# what does it mean files overflow_xxxx.bin while training glove

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm training a word embedding model based on Glove method. While the algorith shows a logger like:

```
$ build/cooccur -memory 4.0 -vocab-file vocab.txt -verbose 2 -window-size 8 < /home/ignacio/data/GUsDany/corpus/GUs_regulon_pubMed.txt > cooccurrence.bin
COUNTING COOCCURRENCES
window size: 8
context: symmetric
max product: 13752509
overflow length: 38028356
Reading vocab from file "vocab.txt"...loaded 145223095 words.
Building lookup table...table contains 228170143 elements.
Processing token: 5478600000
```

The home directory of Glove is filled with files caled `overflow_0534.bin`. Can someone tell whether all is going well?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Everything is OK.

You can view the source code of Glove cooccur program at [Github](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe/blob/master/src/cooccur.c).

At the line 57 of the file:

```
long long overflow_length; // Number of cooccurrence records whose product exceeds max_product to store in memory before writing to disk
```

If your corpus has too many co-occurrence records, then there will be some data to be written into some temp bin disk files.

```
while (1) {
    if (ind >= overflow_length - window_size) { // If overflow buffer is (almost) full, sort it and write it to temporary file
        qsort(cr, ind, sizeof(CREC), compare_crec);
        write_chunk(cr,ind,foverflow);
        fclose(foverflow);
        fidcounter++;
        sprintf(filename,"%s_%04d.bin",file_head,fidcounter);
        foverflow = fopen(filename,"w");
        ind = 0;
    }
```

The variable `overflow_length` depends on your memory settings.

Line 463:

```
if ((i = find_arg((char *)"-memory", argc, argv)) > 0) memory_limit = atof(argv[i + 1]);
```

Line 467:

```
rlimit = 0.85 * (real)memory_limit * 1073741824/(sizeof(CREC));
```

Line 470:

```
overflow_length = (long long) rlimit/6; // 0.85 + 1/6 ~= 1
```

Comment: thanks for reply. so how to avoid massive files preventing me from training models >=300 dimensions?

Comment: @Nacho The `overflow_xxx.bins` files are cache files, so you can just remove them when the `cooccurrence.bin` is generated. If you want to avoid these files, more ram might work.